# Remove object from NSMutableArray if it exists in another array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, collections, nsmutablearray

I am trying to build a quiz based game where you can play with your Facebook friends. I have three sections in a table where the first section shows if its your turn, the second section shows your opponents' turns, and the third section shows your Facebook friends. I have three different `NSMutableArray`s retrieved from the backend, and I want to not display friends if they are already in the game session list.

```
firstCollection = [{id=1,name="test"},{id=2,name="asdf"}];
secondCollection = [{id=3,name="third"}]
facebookCollection = [{id=1,name="test"},{id=3,name="third"},{id=4,name="showthisguy"}]
```

Is there any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[facebookCollection removeObjectsInArray:firstCollection];
[facebookCollection removeObjectsInArray:secondCollection];
```

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html